# Is `composability` a proper word in English?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

Is `composability` a proper word in English ? Suppose I have a set of elements and can *compose* them to create different structures. May I call this property of the set "composability" ?

Comment: What dictionaries have you consulted?

Comment: I did not find it in `m-w.com` but found it in Wikipedia

Comment: It's a possible word, but it would refer to one specific sense of _compose_ only. Say you mean the mathematical sense of two functions `f(x)` composed with `g(x)`, i.e `f(g(x))`. Then if there were some reasons why they couldn't be composed in this sense (say `f(x)` = `1/x` and `g(x)` = `0/x`), they would be uncomposable; and if there weren't, they'd be composable. But there has to be a specific definition for _compose_.

Answer (score 1):

The term exists in the field of software engineering:

> [Composability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composability) is a system design principle that deals with the inter-relationships of components. A highly composable system provides recombinant components that can be selected and assembled in various combinations to satisfy specific user requirements.

It is not a "standard" English word and many who heard it used would assume it was technical jargon from one field or another.

So, in short, you can use it if you have a matching technical use of "compose" but it is highly recommended that you very explicitly define the term before using it.